# Sort list of tags so it best fits the available width

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, tags

I got a `<div>`-Element which has a width of 185px (height does not matter) and I got several textbased Tags with a maximum length of 20 characters.

When I load the page the tags are shown in the div (data comes from a DB), but are ordered alphabetically which leads to the problem that I can have big spaces at the end of the line. In that space a shorter tag could fit perfectly.

I couldn't come up with a order technique which orders by length so the line is best filled before it wraps to the next line. The alphabetical order is not needed here anymore.

Besides JS and HTML, I am able to use LESS and PHP if it's important.

PHTML:

```
<div class="tag-list">
    <?php foreach ($this->tags as $tag): ?>
        <div class="tag-marker"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

The data comes from PHP as an array of tags.

```
[
    {"name":"important","color":"#cccccc"},
    {"name":"normal","color":"#cccccc"},
    {"name":"ignore","color":"#cccccc"},
    ...
]
```

LESS:

```
.tag-list {
    width: 185px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.tag-marker {
    //some styling
}
```

Comment: Could you post what you've got so far, or how you want the result to become? We need some context.

Comment: Please add some code and make a stack snippet.

Comment: I'm assuming that the alphabetical order can be ignored....right?

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, alphabetical order can be ignored

Comment: @BRO_THOM Added code

Comment: You can use correct `width` with `padding` and `text-overflow:ellipsis`, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow